# Black screen when alt-tabbing borderless games in Windows 10

Tags: windows, graphics-card

When I attempt to alt-tab out of a game, or click on something on my second monitor, my primary monitor turns off for a couple seconds before turning back on (full black instead of backlit black). I play all my games in borderless or windowed borderless. Is there a way to prevent the screen from flickering and instead allow for a seamless transition out of the game when alt-tabbing?

The displays are extended. I have the latest versions of Windows and the latest game-oriented Nvidia driver for my 2080 super. I have two Freesync monitors - Nixeus Edg 34 ultrawide (2k 144hz, primary) and Nixeus Edg 27 (2k 144hz, second).

**What I have tried so far:**

1) Turned the Scaling mode in the Nvidia Control Panel to 'No Scaling' for both monitors.

2) Set the refresh rate and resolutions to the proper native settings for both monitors in the Nvidia Control Panel - however the Edg 27 appears to only have an option for 120hz instead of 144hz.

3) Set the games to 'Windowed' which appeared to correct the issue, however I would much rather play in 'Borderless' so I can seamlessly click out of the current game.

I recently built this PC and I did not encounter this issue with my previous build. I am using the same monitors and cables I used with the old PC:

New PC Specs:
Ryzen 3800x, Asus X570-E Strix motherboard, EVGA 2080 Super FTW3 Hybrid, 32 GB Gskill Neo 3600mhz ram (factory overclock), Corsair RM750x Power Supply, 2 Corsair LL140 fans, 3 LL120 fans, Corsair 240mm Pro XT RGB cpu aio, 4 corsair RGB strips (came with the LL120 fans), 1 Commander Pro, 1 Node Pro and 1 RGB Hub.

Games are installed on a Samsung Evo Plus m.2 drive as well as a Samsung QVO drive

Old PC Specs:
Ryzen 3700x,
Asus X570-F Strix motherboard,
Gigabyte 2080 Windforce triple-fan,
32GB Gskill TridentZ 3200mhz ram (factory overclock),
EVGA Supernova P2 750 Power Supply

Games installed on an m.2, 2.5" SSD and a 7200rpm HDD

Edit 1: Less than an hour after I posted the initial question
I talked to a friend of mine and he suggested that the monitor may not be getting enough power to it. Like the genius I am, I had my PC and both monitors plugged into the same dinky powerstrip. I plugged my larger monitor into a different powerstrip and it works perfectly now! I can tab-out with no black screen-flickering. Sorry for the self-answer.

EDIT 2: Less than an hour after the first edit
The issue has returned. I closed Bannerlord 2 and switched to Rust and the problem seemed to return. I closed Rust and went back to Bannerlord 2 and now that game has the issue too.

EDIT 3: Added PSUs and altered formatting to make it more readable, thanks for the suggestions Kadima!

Comment: It's hard to read your PC specs due to a lack of commas separating the components, but I don't see a power supply listed. The parts you are using would have a high requirement for power, but may run at partial capacity if under-powered. Perhaps your friend was right about the power issue but it's the internal power, not the external power that is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Kadima! I have updated the specs accordingly. Both the old build and the new build use 750W power supplies.